# Angular binding for loading doesn't update the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show a loading indicator whenever a user clicks the save button. When the button is clicked, the state changes successfully, but reverting back the value of the `loading` property on scope to the false state doesn't update the UI.

Is it something i'm doing wrong with scope properties, or is this a flaw with angular?

Here's my jsBin: http://jsbin.com/xafexorope/2/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it doesnt work is because Angular's internal dirty-checking loop is not fired. It's because you use a standard setTimeout. Instead of that, either manually call $scope.$apply() at the end of your setTimeout callback, or better, use the angular wrapper $timeout.

Here is your updated jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/devuhovaxa/3/edit

Additionally here the docs for $timeout:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: In my actual application its in the callback for a UserApp.io ajax request, i just used a timeout so the example would work. That being said, I used `$scope.$apply` there, and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Any useful documentation you would recommend regarding this particular issue? Specifically the "dirty-checking" loop and the `$scope.$apply`?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what exactly you are searching for but those posts are pretty nice: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/ and this one http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html